# Adding background image to the selected in an UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I would like to add a background image for the selected text in the UITextView, not for the whole view, as I marked in the below picture.

1. How can I add a background image for the selected text?
2. Or, how can I add one small image before and another one after the
   selected without making the other text move back or forward?

[image]

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: Hi @GabrielePetronella, I did not try anything unfortunately. I don't have much clue about this. I am not looking for a complete solution neither. Some references would be fine.

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

UITextInput protocol should provide everything you need.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Specifically:

[`selectedTextRange`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInput/selectedTextRange)

[`firstRectForRange`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextInput/firstRectForRange%3a)

`firstRectForRange:` which will tell you the rectangle covering a range of characters. If the range of characters spans multiple lines, you have to call it repeatedly. The first time it will give you the first rect and tell you what range that covers. Then, you adjust the range you're asking about to be the remaining characters you're interested in and repeat.